# Can I install an Oracle DB on a Solaris 10/11 VM (not sparc)?

Tags: solaris, database, oracle-database

I have Solaris machines (10/11) which are running on VMware and I am intending on installing a DB on them.
Can I install on Oracle DB if it's not on sparc? if so- where can I find instructions?
If not- What DB can I install on a VM like that?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Oracle DB is available for Solaris x86 as well as SPARC.  Instructions and binaries are in the same places on the Oracle web sites as for other platforms - just make sure to choose the Solaris x86 version instead of the Solaris SPARC version.

Comment: You need to keep the database licensing restrictions in mind when running databases on VMware. Running Solaris on bare metal with Solaris kernel zones running the databases is probably a better approach.